# All browsers can't (normally) open a specific website

Tags: windows, networking, google-chrome, firefox, website

I don't know why but all of my Windows 8 browsers (Firefox, Chrome, IE) fail to open a specific website and all its sub-domains.

**How can I find the problem ?**

**Observation:**

1. I can open this website on my other laptops in home (connected to same router), therefore the problem is about my laptop OS.
2. I've found that I can open this website using a proxy.
3. I try to flush DNS by `ipconfig /flushdns` but it doesn't help at all.
4. This is the `ping` result:

   ```
   Pinging sharif.edu [81.31.160.39] with 32 bytes of data:
   Reply from 192.168.0.11: Destination host unreachable.
   Reply from 192.168.0.11: Destination host unreachable.
   ```

   Output of `ipconfif /all`:

   ```
   Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Emadpres
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Mixed
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No


   Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) WiFi Link 1000 BGN
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::b57e:4a15:4a3c:f71f%13(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.11(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Saturday, November 29, 2014 5:47:37 PM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Wednesday, December 3, 2014 2:52:39 PM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 327985538
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-19-AC-13-FD-F0-BF-97-17-F8-59

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

   Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:9d38:6abd:14ee:28c7:3f57:fff4 (Preferred)
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::14ee:28c7:3f57:fff4%17 (Preferred)
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled

   Tunnel adapter isatap.{5BF73E97-6819-4173-8F3C-2EEECBD61407}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #8
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   ```

Comment: Have you checked the usual things like a virus/malware scan?

Comment: This does sound like a DNS issue. Is the troublesome laptop using the same DNS settings as the laptops that work? Can the other laptops ping the site OK? Is it possible that you have some additional firewalling or webscanning software on the troublesome laptop which is preventing connections to that site?

Comment: @AdamThompson Notice that website get open using proxy! I have a clean windows8 with not antivirus or any software like that. I disabled windows firewall but no help. Is there any place in windows that block a website ? As I said, My other laptops can open and ping fine.

Comment: Are you testing with your laptop at home? Which proxy did you use? What is the output of "ipconfig /all"?

Comment: @AdamThompson DNS resolving succeeded, only pinging the IP address fails. So this is not a DNS issue.

Comment: @WernerHenze I insert ipconfig output.  I use `Tunnel+` service to connect blocked website in my country.

Comment: Can you copy and paste the output from doing a "route print" (without quotes) from a command prompt?
Have you tried running a packet capture (such as Wireshark) while trying to ping?

Comment: @EmAdpres - usually, when using a proxy server, the proxy server performs the DNS lookup. Your OS does not resolve the name at all; it asks the proxy to do this. If it definitely not DNS, and there's no network filter driver or local firewall blocking the connection, I could only think that perhaps you have persistent route setup to 81.31.160.0/24. Check this with the "route print" command and look for a persistent route with a destination beginning with 81.

Comment: Actually - thinking out loud here - it looks like sharif.edu is not just in the 81.31.160.0/24 netblock. For example - nano.sharif.edu is in 213.233.160.0/19. Can you reach both sits by IP? http://81.31.160.39/ and http://213.233.160.10/ - it seems odd that the common factor is "any site which is in the sharif.edu zone", but that it wouldn't be DNS-related. Assuming it's network related, the only common factor is that both networks are on the same ASN - but your laptop should not be concerned with ASNs or BGP.

Answer (score 0):

If pinging your gateway works (`ping 192.168.0.1`) but a `ping 81.31.160.39` returns

> Reply from 192.168.0.11: Destination host unreachable.

and `ipconfig` says that 192.168.0.11 is your own IP address, then it looks like your routes are corrupt (check with `route print`) or there is some Antivirus or Firewall running on your computer that disallows traffic to 81.31.160.39.